# Recover /etc folder with dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

I accidentally deleted the / etc folder (system configuration files) `sudo rm -rf /etc` from my xubuntu, I don't have much experience with informatics, I'm starting now, I've been reading some forums on what I could do, however I didn't find any with the exact problem that I have, because I have dual boot windows 10 and xubuntu and I can boot on windows.

Is it possible to access the xubuntu files, which I need, through windows to recover them? If so, how do I do it?

My idea to fix the pc was to recover the files first and then reinstall xubuntu. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Just boot to a live USB of Xubuntu and back up the files you want to keep. Then, you can reinstall and restore the files. That should work just fine. Your files should be in /home/<username>/ and the disk should mount automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try that tomorrow, and give you back the result.

Comment: So It did'nt work exactly as I expected, I reinstall xubuntu from a live USB, but now I have two Xubuntus, and one Windows. I recoverd the files with a software from windows, called diskinternals, so I don't have to keep the other xubuntu without the /etc folder. Shall I delete that xubuntu and allocate it's memory to the new? On the bios the xubuntu without the /etc folder dosen't appear anymore, but with gparted that memory is still ocupied with a xubuntu partition

Comment: You can delete one and then update grub. Make sure you update grub after (from inside the working install). It's `sudo update-grub` and that should get you fixed the rest of the way. Just go ahead and delete it. You can later grow your partition (again from a live USB) to take up that space (if needed). By pure coincidence, I was responding to you when your message came through. To use the live USB, you select to 'try' and not the 'install'. That gives you a live environment that you can use.

Comment: If I delete one of them, and I will delete the new one because the other has my applications already installed, won't I delete grub as well?

Comment: You recovered your data. So, use your new clean install and you'll have to install the applications all over again. Now would also be a good time to look into learning how to backup your system so that you can recover if this happens again. If you delete your old one, you can still use grub - just don't delete it. If you do happen to delete it, use `boot-repair` and that will get you squared away. If you don't know what boot-repair is, then a search will explain it well enough. But, just don't delete grub and update grub when you're done.

Comment: Thank You very much, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad ya got it sorted. It's time to learn how to properly backup your system. I like to use something called 'luckyBackup' and many folks are fond of 'Timeshift'.

Answer (score 1):

There's no sense in trying to repair this. It'll be faster, easier, and less prone to faults if you just backup your existing data and and do a clean installation.

So, start with the same live USB disk you used before and boot to it. Don't install at this point. At this point, plugin an external USB drive and backup everything from /home or /home/user if you have just one user to worry about.

Once that's complete, and it may take a while depending on how much data you're moving, go ahead and start the installation process. Though you may want to at least visually verify that your backup was successful. (You could do things like rsync, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.)

Next, just do a clean install. During the install process, choose to use the whole disk - formatting everything and basically starting over with a clean slate. It will look something like this:

[image]

If you're given the opportunity, you can consider trying the top option which should do a clean installation while keeping your /home directories as they are. However, given the damage done, I'd suggest a full installation.

Let that finish and when prompted reboot - except, once again, you're going to boot to the live USB instance.

Now, copy the /home/user files back to where they came from. Wait patiently for them to complete and then reboot after you're done restoring the files. Make sure you're showing all the files, including the .dot (hidden) files.

This time, remove the USB when prompted and boot to the hard disk. Your files should be restored. When you reinstall the software you had before, your config files should still be there and that will save you a great deal of time.